# Remove English United States from unattend.txt

Tags: windows-server-2003, deployment, unattended

I am trying to create an automated Windows Server 2003 build, everything is working fine, however, after the process has finished I am left with two keyboard layouts, English UK and English US. How can I remove English US via the unattend.txt file, as I won't have access to the server after it has build, so I will not be able to remove it manually.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We use

```
[Unattended]
    KeyboardLayout="United Kingdom"

[GuiUnattended]
    OEMSkipRegional=1
    TimeZone=085

[RegionalSettings]
    InputLocale=0809:00000809
    InputLocale_DefaultUser=0809:00000809
    UserLocale=00000809
    UserLocal_DefaultUser=00000809
    SystemLocale=00000809
    Language=00000809
    LanguageGroup=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17
```

which does the trick.